# Dealing with duplicates based on certain conditions SQL hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with two columns:

```
Key    Date
1      a
1      a
1      NULL
2      NULL
2      NULL
3      b
3      NULL
4      c
4      c
```

I need final output like this:

```
Key     Date
1       a
2       NULL
3       b
4       c
```

In other words, a key can have multiple equal dates,multiple equal dates and a null, all nulls, or one date one null.
I need to remove duplicates from my table but am not able to create these rules. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the sql Query:

```
select Distinct a.[Key],b.[Date] from TEST a left join TEST b on a.[Key] = b.[Key] and b.[Date] is not null
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, key 2 have both dates as null. I still need this key to show up with one null. Does this query take care of that?

Comment: Have you run the query?

Answer (score 1):

This will give the desired result

```
  select distinct key, date from Table_Name  , 
( select key as x ,size(collect_list(date)) as a from Table_Name group by key )
temp   
where (Table_Name.key = temp.x and a=0) OR  date is not null;
```